# Cauchy Riemann equations - polar form question

Tags: complex-analysis

Doing some exercises from a book and it says the following -

[image]

I dont get this. The bottom line differentiates both sides with respect to r and  $ru_{r}$ becomes $ru_{rr} + ru_r$. Where is the $ru_{r}$ coming from, surely it should just be $ru_{rr}$?

Comment: It's the product rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall $(fg)' =f'g+g'f$.

So 
$$\eqalign{{\partial\over \partial r} (r u_r)&=  r {\partial\over \partial r}  ( u_r)+u_r{\partial\over \partial r} (r  ) \cr&=ru_{rr}+  u_r\cdot 1\cr &=ru_{rr}+  u_r .}$$

(By the way, you have a type in your second to last sentence. You should have "...and $ru_r$ becomes $ru_{rr}+  u_r$".)